# Force Qualtrics Matrix to Accordion

Tags: javascript, accordion, qualtrics

Is there a way to force Qualtrics to use the Accordion Format for Matrix questions? Perhaps with JavaScript? According to the documentation, it seems to be up to the device and the device is not good at knowing when to use it.

> Matrix Table
>
> The Matrix Table question type has three viewable formats for mobile
>   devices: Accordion, Normal, and Scrollable.
>
> ACCORDION FORMAT
>
> The Accordion Format for Matrix Tables is turned on by enabling the
>   Mobile Friendly setting in the question Editing Pane. When this box is
>   checked, the Matrix Table will display in the Accordion Format on
>   mobile devices if the table is too large to fit on the screen. If the
>   table is small, the question will display in Normal Format.
>
> We recommend enabling the Mobile Friendly setting for all Matrix Table
>   questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the left label column wide enough, it will force it to accordian on all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that forces the "mobile friendly" accordion display that uses CSS. you can add it in the "Look & Feel > Custom CSS" field of your survey:

```css
    @media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
      .q-matrix.desktop th[scope="row"] {
        width: 2080px !important;
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

In detail this will work like this:

- Due to the media query, it will only affect small screens (i.e. smartphones). 780px is a breakpoint that Qualtrics uses to switch display of question types to the mobile view
- `.q-matrix.desktop th[scope="row"]` will select all item texts (the left label column)

If the page is first accessed, Qualtrics will evaluate, that the left label column is too wide (due to our css change) and switch to the mobile display of the question (it will also change class `desktop` to `mobile`)